# When middleware passes error to next, where should I get the the error in my route handler?

Tags: node.js

So, I'm using to writing router handlers as such,

```
router.route('/').get(function myHandler(req, res, next){
  res.json("hurray")
})
```

What if I want to pass in a middleware that can pass an error as such?

```
function stupidMiddleware(req, res,next){
   next(new Error("Something went wrong"));
}
router.route('/').get(stupidMiddleware, function myHandler(req, res, next){
  res.json("hurray")
})
```

Question: How do I pickup the error in `myHandler`?

Can I just do the following without any side-effects?

```
function stupidMiddleware(req, res,next){
   next(new Error("Something went wrong"));
}
router.route('/').get(stupidMiddleware, function myHandler(err, req, res, next){
  if(err){
    //handle it
  } 
  res.json("hurray")
})
```

Comment: Errors are usually handled by an error handler middleware that you add after all of your routes.

Comment: I'm familiar with that. However what if I've got a pre middlware that's executed before my handler. In the provided example the pre middleware pases an error as `next(err)` which is recommended afaik. This means by handler will need to pass it along (again by calling `next(err)`) so the error handler can pick it up, no? Assuming above is correct, how does my main route handler notice there's an error so it in turn can do a `next(err)`?

Comment: no, you don't have to pass errors along through each middleware. middleware shouldn't need to care about what middleware happened or failed previously.

Comment: Ehmm, but in the above, when `stupidMiddleware` calls `next(err)` which handler picks it up? Next in line right? Or the next in line that has this method signature? `function(err, req, res, next)`? Ahh, the latter that's probably it!

Comment: Next in line that adds a function with those 4 parameters. :) whether it be in that route, or in the global app.

Comment: What exactly is `router`? it affects how my answer code is structured..

Comment: @kevinB, with router meant `myHandler`. But think you just confirmed my suspicion with "Next in line that adds a function with those 4 parameters. " . That makes total sense. And for the record, I know middleware shouldn't be linked, just suddenly had this creeping feeling that `myHandler` should handler errors of stuff thrown before it. Luckily it doesn't. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define an error handler middleware after all of your routes, your routes do not need to listen for errors from previous middleware.

```
router.route('/').get(stupidMiddleware, function myHandler(req, res, next){
  res.json("hurray")
}).use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.log(err, err.stack);
  res.sendStatus(500);
});
```

---

In the above code i used `.use` on the route, i'm not sure if .use with the error handler signature actually works on routers, usually this is done on the `app` instead. It is not documented. http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: Yep all confirmed. I exactly always have a error handler at the end. Just somehow had this wrong brainwave questioning my setup. Anyway, cheers for clearing that up